# Why does it keep saying the size of a hashMap is zero after I keep putting things in it?

Tags: java, hashmap

What I am trying to do is add rooms to a hash map (I don't want duplicates) with `addRoom()`. I am then passing them to the controller with `getRoom(String)` or `getRooms()`.

The problem is, as you can see with my multiple System.out.prints, the size keeps staying at `0`, no matter how many time I run `addRoom()`.

Am I doing something wrong or is the problem somewhere else in the program?

```
package calendar;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Building {

    String buildingName = null;

    private Map<String, Classroom> rooms =
        new HashMap<String, Classroom>();

    public Building() {
    }
    public Building(String name){
        buildingName=name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rooms
     */
    public Map<String, Classroom> getRooms() {
        System.out.println("room size from building.java:" +
            rooms.size());
        return rooms;
    }

    public Classroom getRoom(String roomName) {
        if (rooms.containsKey(roomName)) {
            return rooms.get(roomName);
        }
        return new Classroom("null");
    }

    /**
     * @param rooms the rooms to set
     */
    public void setRooms(Map<String, Classroom> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public void addRoom(String roomNumber) {
        System.out.println("Room added: "+roomNumber +" to "+ 
            buildingName+ " size:"+rooms.size());
        rooms.put(roomNumber, new Classroom(roomNumber));
    }
}
```

I call this method from a parser so the code is a bit verbose but I will cut down on it and try to paste just the relevant parts:

```
private Map<String, Building> currentBuilding = new HashMap<String, Building>();
```

now this is in a for loop that goes over all the blocks of data that need to be parsed:
    currentBuilding.put(building, new Building(building));
    currentBuilding.get(building).addRoom(room);

Where building and room are Strings. The buildings get initiated as they should. And obviously I want the room of each building to be in its corresponding building but this does not seem to happen as intended.

Comment: I don't think the bug is in this class.  Can you show the code that's calling these methods?

Comment: Indeed, I suspect something keeps calling setRooms() with an empty map is an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your class works perfectly! Just made some fixes

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Building {

 String buildingName = null;
 private static Map<String, Classroom> rooms =
        new HashMap<String, Classroom>();

 public Building() {
 }

 public Building(String name) {
    buildingName = name;
 }

 /**
  * @return the rooms
  */
 public Map<String, Classroom> getRooms() {
    System.out.println("room size from building.java:"
            + rooms.size()); 
    return rooms;
 }

 public Classroom getRoom(String roomName) {
    if (rooms.containsKey(roomName)) {
        return rooms.get(roomName);
    }
    return new Classroom("null");
 }

 /**
  * @param rooms the rooms to set
  */
 public void setRooms(Map<String, Classroom> rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms; // did you use this method to initialize map?
 }

 public void addRoom(String roomNumber) {
    rooms.put(roomNumber, new Classroom(roomNumber));
    System.out.println("Room added: " + roomNumber + " to "
            + buildingName + " size:" + rooms.size()); // print info after action
 }
}
```

and usage

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Building building = new Building("first building");
        building.addRoom("1"); // add room 1
        building.addRoom("2"); // add room 2
        building.addRoom("3"); // add room 3
        System.out.println(building.getRooms().size()); 
    }
```

ouput

```
Room added: 1 to first building size:1
Room added: 2 to first building size:2
Room added: 3 to first building size:3
room size from building.java:3
3
```

Nevertheless, your class works as expected, the problem can be in class usage, how do you handle reference to Building class, may be you want it to be static?